# Creating friendly URLs with mod_rewrite in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have searched this forum and have done extensive google search and have not been able to figure it out. I have many links that look like:

- `mysite.com/example6.php?id=play-game`
- `mysite.com/example6.php?id=watch-tv`
- `mysite.com/example6.php?id=go-outside`

I have tried lots of different code putting this in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /example6.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id/(.*) example6.php?id=$1
</IfModule>
```

and many more attempts but nothing works to get my URLS to look like this:

- `mysite.com/example6/play-game`
- `mysite.com/example6/watch-tv`
- `mysite.com/example6/go-outside`

I do have mod_rewrite enabled on my server. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^example6/(.*)$ example6.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Your first example (`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /example6.php?id=$1 [L]`) would correctly work for urls like "/play-game.html", and your second example (`RewriteRule ^id/(.*) example6.php?id=$1`) would correctly work for urls like "/id/play-game".

Comment: I've tried using RewriteRule ^example6/(.*)$ /example6.php?id=$1 [L]
but it does nothing the links remain mysite.com/example6.php?id=play-game  Does it matter where I put my .htaccess file?

Comment: I just made a change. I removed the leading slash from the second component. Try this now.

Comment: For rewrites that don't match full urls like "http://" (e.g. for rewrites that match regexes, the second component is understood to be a file path, so the leading slash makes it relative to the root of the filesystem. No leading slash makes it relative to the web folder, which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still get no results.  This is how I have my links set up <a href="http://www.mysite.com/example6.php?id=play-game">play game</a> Does this matter when using rewrite?  I can't think of anything else at the moment why I can't get this to work

Comment: You should be just linking directly to the desired urls: `<a href="http://mysite.com/example6/play-game">play game</a>`.

Comment: This would be my problem then.  I am new to this.  I have lots of links like that all going to a template page (example6) but I need the URL for this template page to be different for all the different links I have. I added the .php?id= to all links and thought that this is a query php string and then would be able to mod_rewrite. Does that make sense?

Comment: No, that doesn't make sense. I don't really understand what you are trying to say. How does this having anything to do with jquery at all? And it doesn't really have much to do with php either except that your scripts are written in php, but this is about urls. This is all a mod_rewrite and html issue. When you link to something in html, the web browser goes exactly to that url, just what you enter. So you *have to*  go to your desired end urls. Mod_rewrite is a way of telling apache to treat certain urls like others when asked for.

Comment: So when you link to `http://mysite.com/example6/play-game`, that's where your web browser goes and that's what you see in the address bar. Then your web server, when getting this request, uses mod_rewrite to say "Okay, I'll pretend the url is "http://mysite.com/example6.php?id=play-game". And then processes the request as if that were the case.

Comment: I see. What I was doing is backwards.  Having mysite.com/example6.php?id=play-game be the link and trying to have mod_rewrite pretend the url is http://mysite.com/example6/play-game.  If I did do it this way won't it be more search engine friendly?  If I were to set up my links like you have described above what would the mod_rewrite look like?  Sorry I am just learning.

Comment: Linking directly to the desired urls is *definitely* search-engine friendly. The web crawlers (like google-bot) that build search indexes are seeing the urls you link. What you put in the HTML has to be good for search engines. Anyway, the mod_rewrite in this answer should work if you set the links right.

Comment: Your last comment seems cut off.

Comment: So all of my direct links would be: mysite.com/mysite/play-game
      mysite.com/mysite/watch-tv
      mysite.com/mysite/go-outside                       
But I do not have indexes for any of these links.  I have one page mysite.com/example6 that would be the index for all my links.  But I need the url of mystie.com/example6 changed to the link that the user is clicking on. For Ex. if they click on mysite.com/mysite/watch-tv they would actually be taken to mysite.com/example6 but the url would read something like mysite.com/mysite/watch-tv.  Is this feasible with mod_rewrite? Thanks much

Comment: @joe, yes it is possible, as I've already described. Please follow my instructions. I've already explained the whole thing twice in a lot of detail. If you still don't understand, I don't what I else I can say to explain it to you.